# Qt app starts on device where it was compiled, but not on others

Tags: c++, qt, build, build-error

I built a Qt 5.12 app on Ubuntu then moved it to another computer (the very same Ubuntu system) - and it gave me a "__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length, version Qt_5" at start (and quit)...
When I try with a default Qt windowed starting project (one window, nothing else) and copy the executable to the other computer (where my app is failing), it works. So I think the problem is not in the project setup and the kit.

Very strange is that several weeks ago everything was fine. I don't have any idea what has changed since. I presume that there is a version conflict with a library, but I am not a linux pro and dont't know how to figure that out.

It would be great if any of you could help. :)

Comment: can you ldd your executable and check if all dependencies are met. QT .so files are not shipped with the executables so maybe you are missing one of those

Comment: I did, all dependencies are met. BUT I get an "undefined symbol: __cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length, version Qt_5".

Comment: I figured out that this exception is from libstdc++, and further tried a workaround with forcing my gcc to c++98 because of changed allocation methods that raise exceptions by default - but it didn't work.

Comment: there is a tool called linuxdeployqt. it can be used to create a bundle of your project and all needed libs. (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PDzlT_ODpM8) this is a link that shows a demo of the tool (you can skip first 6.5 mins as he demonstrates how to build the project inside qt).